# No apt in tensorflow docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, docker-compose

I need to use a legacy version of tensorflow to compile a project. To do this, we setup a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  exercise:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: practical_4
    environment:
      DATASET: cifar
    volumes:
      - "./:/app/"

    command: bash run.sh
```

My Dockerfile looks like so:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.2

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/

RUN ['apt', 'install', 'python-pip']
#RUN ['pip', 'install', 'matplotlib']
```

And finally the run script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$DATASET"

# Install dependencies
pip install matplotlib
pip install numpy
pip install pickle

if [ $DATASET = "cifar" ]; then
  python cifar_cnn.py
else
  python mnist_cnn.py
fi
```

Now, when running `docker-compose up` the procedure fails. For some the command apt is not found..?

```
Step 4/5 : RUN ['apt', 'install', 'python-pip']
 ---> Running in 39c9c48240b5
/bin/sh: 1: [apt,: not found
ERROR: Service 'exercise' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ['apt', 'install', 'python-pip']' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Why is that, and how can I solve this?

Comment: You need double quotes `["apt", "install", "python-pip"]`.  With single quotes it's not a JSON array, and Docker tries to run the whole thing (including brackets) as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).

So if you want to use exec form, try:

```
RUN ["apt", "install", "python-pip"]
```

There's also shell form:

```
RUN apt install python-pip
```

That form would be more appropriate in your case, as exec form usually used when you want to run command in different(not `/bin/sh -c`) shell, for example:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "apt install python-pip"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RUN apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y python-pip
```